# SQL Server : Is it necessary to disable SA user for security issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, security

We have a website that will published in national grade with millions of users with `Microsoft Sql Server RDBMS`.

I need to know is it **necessary** to disable SA login for security issues like DOS attacks ? I know it is good to do that, but want to know is there any better way for making my server more secure without doing that ?

Answer (score 3):

Renaming or disabling sa account is just part of the story.

There is no drawback if you disable 'sa' account.

It means if you have databases whose owners are sa, there isn't a problem.

System databases like master, or tempDb require that sa be the database owner.

If you try to change the owner of system databases you will receive 15109 error.

Similar situation is with SQL Server Agent jobs, owned by sa. They won't fail, either.

IMO good practice is to have at least one account enabled with sysadmin role.

Comment: I don't want to change owner of system databases. I have a personal database for my project. I just want to know 'Should I disable sa login in my sql server for something like dos attacks or not?

Comment: It is part of good practice. There is no need to change the owner of the database. The internal process work fine even if sa is disabled.

Comment: So It's better to disable that ?

Comment: Yes. As I wrote above, at first I will create another login let say myAdmin or system and put it in the sysadmin role.

Comment: Thank you. I'll add sysadmin role to another login and then disable that.